# How do i get last div to expand parent's height?

Tags: html, css

So i have `.cont` that's centered in using position absolute and is height 80% of body.

Inside it there are two divs. One is fixed height. And other one needs to expand to rest of parent, `.cont`.

So How do i make it expand to parent.

One other requirement is that content in both of these needs to be vertically and horizontally centered.

```
body
   .cont
      .top
      .fillRest
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24jocwu5/

1. make .fillRest Expand to rest of .cont.
2. vertically and Horizontally center h1 headings in both divs.

Don't Use calc()

can use display table, flow, position, and other tricks.

[image]

Comment: .top has fixed `height 100px.` so something like  80% for .fillRest won't work as it's sibling isn't going to be 20% most of the time.

Comment: i've been trying to use table-row but then no value of position works for centering heading and content boxes in middle.

Comment: found my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/24jocwu5/7/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  Absolutely position the white container with a top-padding that equals the height of your fixed-height top div.  Then give the top div a z-index so it goes over your white box:

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/24jocwu5/2/

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #3dd;
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: helvetica;
}
.cont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: #1af;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 80%;
}
.top {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.fillRest {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Pretty awesome, i think similar hack is used by bootstrap also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this

```
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cont > div {
  display: flex;
}

.fillRest {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z24x0rvo/)

Comment: :D ---flexbox very soon

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? 
Only position fixed and right and left 0

http://jsfiddle.net/pabliiitoo/24jocwu5/1/

```
.fillRest {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't touch the height at all. I want white area to expand to blue area. I cant use percentage height because blue parent,.cont is also percentage based and sibliing is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to expand the .fillRest to the rest of its parent .cont, you need to set it's height to a percentage. I estimate about 20~30% is what you want in order to maintain a similar look to the image you've provided here.

To test it, grab a very large paragraph full of letters and anything you want and put it where the 'Content' text is, that way you will be able to see it expanding in a responsive way. Another suggestion I will give you is to make your width percentages as well, so that they expand according to the width of the screen responsively.

Let me know if this helped you, otherwise I can take another look :)

CSS

```
.cont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; 
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1af;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: blue div is also % based so setting inner white content div % while there is sibling won't work

Comment: sorry, which blue exactly?

Comment: `.cont` div that is centered

Comment: when you mean 'make it expand to parent' you mean you want .fillRest to 'expand to rest of parent' .cont vertically as you insert more text or content inside of it right? If this is true, then having a % height will achieve this, unless you mean something else. I'm sorry if I am not giving you an accurate answer, it's a bit difficult to understand the implementation you're trying to achieve.

Comment: No as i said .fillRest should fill the rest of available height and not expand based on it's children.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the way you're going about this is all wrong. But maybe something like this would work.

http://jsfiddle.net/24jocwu5/5/

CSS selectors I changed:

```
.cont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: #1af;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}

.fillRest {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: while it's not wrong, and does work for most cases, However, you coverted top from fixed height to percentage. Which is fine. But i just want to know how to do this without having percentage vals. As there are some designs that i brainstorm and they need this behavior.

Comment: All the code is sloppy, if I'm being honest. Keep playing around with it. Whats the content in the white area? Paragraph? Image? Link?

Comment: it could be anything.but whatever it's white area will have scrollbar. but it should be centered inside white area. and if it overflows white area then white area will have scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

This is Summary Of Ways.. First two ways posted here--

1. [FlexBox Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308901/how-do-i-get-last-div-to-expand-parents-height/29309253#29309253) 100% WORKS
2. [Padding Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308901/how-do-i-get-last-div-to-expand-parents-height/29309196#29309196) 80% WORKS. Useful But not exactly.
3. Css Table Cell and Table Rows 100% WORKS. From Me.
4. Using Calcs Simplest One. 100% WORKS. From me.

**Css Table Cell**: http://jsfiddle.net/24jocwu5/7/
***.cont*** is The Table. **top & fillRest** are table rows, and there is **cell** which can have vertical align middle.

**Calc Method**: http://jsfiddle.net/24jocwu5/9/
*Works but doesn't scale well if content increases, so need to use another div which can contain the content. Like so http://jsfiddle.net/24jocwu5/10/*

**Default code:**

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; }

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #3dd;
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: helvetica;
}

.cont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: #1af;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 80%;
}
```